# How to build files as root in sublime on mac?

Tags: macos, build, sublimetext2, root, sudo

Today after I updated **OS X** to 10.9.5 and **Xcode** on **Mac**, I encounter a problem with **Sublime Text 2** that when I write a Hello World program in C++, and run build, it says
**`Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.`**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreeing to Xcode license outside Sublime Text may help resolve the issue.

Running sudo xcrun cc should bring up the cli version of the Xcode license agreement. Another option is to open Xcode.app and agree in the GUI.